# computed.reads does not fire observers when the binding is null

Tags: ember.js

I am able to pass a `selection` into a component

```
{{my-component selection=model.account }}
```

In the component there is a oneWay binding to the selection

```
_selection: computed.reads('selection'),
```

I have an observer over `_selection`

```
  selectionUpdated: observer('_selection.id',function() {
    //Do something
  }),
```

When `model.account` is changed, the `selectionUpdated` method is called correctly, however, when `model.account` is set to `null` it does no fire!

Why is this?

Comment: Why not set it directly on `selection.id`? Is `_selection` used elsewhere?

Comment: Because the value of `_selection` is changed throughout the component, I don't want these changes to be propagated up to the binding but I want changes to the binding to be propagated down to the component.

Comment: Does [readOnly](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_readOnly) behave in the same manner?

Comment: Well you can't use `.set()` on a readOnly so that will not work.  At least I am guessing so.  The docs are very unclear, they seem to imply the onWay propagates back up which it does not.